# filter thunderbird email by attachment type

Tags: email, thunderbird, zip, email-filter

I'm getting malware sent to me as .zip attachments that are zipped up exe files. I want to setup message filters to catch them but I can't seem to find a way to do that. I tried setting up a *customize header* but the value I was looking for was apparently in the attachment and not in the header. If I *view source* of the email there is the line **Content-Type: application/zip;** But it seems to be the actual attachment and *body contains* doesn't pick it up.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I would like to do the same but with image files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionalty right now, although looking through the Mozilla bug and feature request lists - there are several people asking for this.

It is probably worth you raising a request at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ and seeing if they listen.

Hope this helps.